# symbol lookup error for ghostscript and pdftopdf

Tags: printing, symbols, ghostscript, ubuntu-20.04, cups

I am trying to print a file using cups and getting a symbol not found error.

```
yoprinter: symbol lookup error: yoprinter: undefined symbol: pdftopdf

yoprinter: symbol lookup error: yoprinter: undefined symbol: ghostscript
```

yoprinter is basically the print queue name I am trying to print to.

cups version: 2.3.3

OS: ubuntu 20.04

file: I am getting this error with every file I am trying to print

Answer (score 0):

The bug was related to configuration issue. I installed both the cups and cups-filters in my local dir `/home/surajkulriya/cupsContent` and started cups-daemon using `sudo /home/surajkulriya/cupsContent/sbin/cupsd -f` and it worked well without any error.